# On button click same row checkbox should be checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have placed a button and checkbox at end of each row of the table. I want now is that if I click button in row 1 then checkbox only in row 1 gets checked and so on. code is working fine if I go from 1st to last row turn by turn.
Problem occurs if I click directly on for eg. 2nd row. if I click in 2nd row then the checkbox in 1st row is selected.

I have tried matching the ids of button and checkbox control but that is not possible as the name in id will always be different.

```
  cols += '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block" onclick="req_ser()" id="check_btn' + limit + '" value="' + data + '">Request</button></td>';

cols +='<td><input type="checkbox" class="chec" id="check' + limit + '" value="' + data + '" disabled="disabled"></input></td>';


function req_ser() {    
    var sl_num = [];
    var count = 0;
    for (var bv = 0; bv <= limit; bv++) {
        var stai;       
        var bvv = bv + 1;
        var cls = document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block");
        var chs = document.getElementsByClassName("chec")
        cls[bv].id = "check_btn" + (bv + 1);
        chs[bv].id = "check" + (bv + 1);
        alert(cls[bv].id);
        alert(chs[bv].id);
        //stai = $('#check' + bvv + '').on(':click');
        //stai = $('#check' + bvv + '').is(':clicked'); 
        //stai = $('#check' + bvv + '').data(':clicked', true); 
            $('#check' + bvv + '').prop('checked', true);
            stai = $('#check' + bvv + '').is(':checked');       
        if (stai == true) {
                sl_num.push({
                    "serial": document.getElementById("slnchk" + bvv + "").innerText,
                });            
            break;            
        }
    }
```

expected result is whichever row button I click only that row checkbox should be checked. Please guide regarding this.

Comment: jquery .closest() and .find() should solve your problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with `.closest()` and `.find()` in jquery.

Example:

```js
$('td .btn').on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.chec').prop("checked", true);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block">Request</button></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="chec" disabled="disabled"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block">Request</button></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="chec" disabled="disabled"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block">Request</button></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="chec" disabled="disabled"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not too difficult with just vanilla JS:

- A click listener calls the `checkit` function.
- Inside the function, all the code is wrapped in an `if` block so it only runs if the clicked element is one of the buttons (which, in this case, are identified by the `checkBtn` class).

  ---
- The function automatically has access to the event that triggered it. We refer to this argument as `event` for ease of reading.
- The event's `target` property gives us the button that was clicked.
- From there, we get the `closest` ancestor element with the tagName `TR`, and we call it `row`.
- Within this row, we get all the `input` elements, take the first one, and call it `checkbox`.

  ---
- To this checkbox, we add the attribute "`checked`" (with an empty string as its value).
  Note: The lines that are commented out would let the user toggle the "check" by clicking again.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", checkit);

function checkit(event){
  if(event.target.classList.contains("checkBtn")){
    const row = event.target.closest("TR");
    const checkbox = row.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0];
    //if(checkbox.checked){ checkbox.removeAttribute("checked"); }
    //else{
      checkbox.setAttribute("checked", "");
    //}
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><button class="checkBtn">Click me</button></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="one" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button class="checkBtn">Click me</button></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="two" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Alternatively (and if speed is not a concern), you can add a separate eventListener to each button as you create it. In this case, the `if` condition would be unnecessary.

This code could be shorter but the example is more explicit for the sake of clarity.